# Need help regarding power source for a 60V BLDC motor

Tags: brushless-dc-motor

I'm mostly new to electronics and stack exchange sites. I'm developing a small, lightweight, real life car (2 seater) for my school project. It is going to be run by a motor. I've chosen a **brushless DC motor rated at 60V 1000W**. That means its current consumption should be 16.66A according to my calculation.

I've chosen **5 x 12V 7.5A Lead-acid batteries** as my power source. When connected in series-parallel , it should provide 60V 37.5A if I'm not wrong.
My car should run for **at least 1 hour continuously at max. speed**.

Now, my question is, **will the motor be able to run for that amount of time with this power source**? I mean, **will the battery be completely dead before 1 hour or can it run for at least that amount of time**? I need much help regarding this calculation.

I've searched for solution to this problem everywhere. But I've mostly found nothing or I couldn't understand anything.

I'm new here, so please pardon my mistakes and I might not understand many technical terms. It'd be highly appreciated if you could keep the answers basic.
The image shows info provided by the battery manufacturer.[image: The battery capacity is 7.5Ah]

Comment: Interesting project. Please provide a schematic drawing showing how you will connect the batteries. Series and parallel are different things, so I don't know what "series-parallel" means. Also, please clarify the capacity of the battery. "7A" is not a capacity. Capacity is normally given in Amp-hours (Ah) or Watt-hours (Wh).

Comment: Your calculations are wrong in that they do not include a 3x start-up current or losses in any power converters, etc. Your  calculations are only good for a steady RPM with no un-expected loads or conversion losses.

Comment: I shall try to provide the schematics as soon as possible. The battery capacity is 7.5Ah. By 'series-parallel', I meant, I would connect the batteries in series and in parallel simultaneously. That should theoretically provide me with 60V 37.5A.

Comment: Draw out how you plan to connect them. You'll see that connecting them in series and parallel at the same time simply short circuits them, destroying them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have 5 batteries in series, you will have 60V at 7.5 Ah. If you have 5  batteries in parallel, you will have 12V at 37.5Ah. You cannot connect them in series and parallel simultaneously.

I would like to introduce you to the concept of energy. The energy in a battery is approximately equal to the voltage * capacity. So each battery has 7.5Ah * 12V = 90Wh. With 5 batteries, you will have 5 * 90 = 450 Wh. This is the energy content of the batteries. It cannot be changed by re-arranging the battery connections.

With 450 Wh, you will be able to supply 1000 Watts for maybe 10-15 minutes. In theory it would be 450Wh / 1000W = 0.45 hours = 27 minutes. But in the real world, you cannot get full capacity from a lead acid battery if you discharge it rapidly.

Also please note that motors are often rated by output power. A motor that puts out 1000W of mechanical power will likely consume 1200W of input power. So that makes it even worse. It is hard to get efficiencies higher than 85% or so in small motors.

However, based on my knowledge of things like e-bikes and other personal electric vehicles, I would say that a 450 Wh battery should be able to propel a very lightweight vehicle for 1 hour at a modest speed. Faster than walking. Maybe jogging speed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarifying. That means, I should need at least 17 batteries to remain on the safe side? Any suggestions regarding how I can run the 60V 1000W motor without spending so much behind batteries?

Comment: I don't think you need 17 batteries. You can run the motor at less than full speed and less than full power for one hour. If you have a specific speed and time you need to meet, then please add that to the original question by editing it.

Answer (score 2):

You will learn a lot about batteries on your project!  I have been working for 40+ years and still finding things out about them.

The short answer is no.  Batteries are given their amp-hour rating at the optimum discharge rate, about 300 or 400 milliamps for this size, and at 7.5 amps you might get about 0.4 hours.  During that 24 minutes, your voltage will steadily drop, and you will be at less than 10 volts at the end.

Also, you won't have 60 volts if you place them in parallel, only 12 volts, unless you meant 25 batteries.

Look for data sheets with discharge curves at different currents.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to read the whole question.                                     That means, I won't be able to run the motor with that power source?           I meant, I would connect 5 batteries in series to get 60V and would connect them in parallel 'at the same time' to get 37.5A.

Comment: When the 5 batteries, you have 7.5 amp-hours x 5 or 37.5 amp-hours when in parallel, if that's what you mean.  However, when in series, you do get your 60 volts but still have only 7.5 amp-hours. At 16.6 amps peak output, you would theoretically get 7.5 / 16.6 hours, which would give you 27 minutes.  In practice at this high level, you would only get about ten minutes.  However, the actual motor current is proportional to torque, so you won't be drawing full current most of the time.

Comment: @AzwadAkbarSymoom How are you going to connect 5 batteries in series and in parallel at the same time? First gear in your car lets you pull very heavy things, but fifth gear lets you go fast. So that is like saying that since you want to pull very heavy things fast, you'll just use first gear and fifth gear at the same time.

Answer (score -1):

interesting job.
some wrong in u'r calculations such as blew.

1) when connected 5 batt 12v 7.5amp in series
that work- 5×12v= 60v 7.5 amp.
2) when connected 5 batt 12v 7.5amp in parallel
that work - 5×7.5amp=37.5amp 12v.

because-
amp multiply paralal connection.
volt multiplu series connection.
if u want 60v 37.5 amp, u need 5×5= 25 batt.
u can try 5 batt 60v 7.5amp for 1000w motor
just 8/10 min on load.

My Suggestion:
5×12v (20/25amp) for 30/60 min.
(depending speed, load variation)
Thank u.